# Programatically detect presence of hardware call/hang up keys

Tags: android

One of my clients wants a code method that returns a boolean. True if the Android phone has hardware red/green call/hang up keys and false if it does not.

Sonething like this :

```
public void keyFeedbackFromInput(KeyEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN 
        && (event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_VIRTUAL_HARD_KEY) != 0) {
    // perform your logic here
  }
}
```

But not in a key press event as in the code snippet above. He needs to determine this up front if a phone has physical red/green keys or virtual ones.

Is it possible and if yes can someone provide a code sample to achieve this?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need this information? Android doesn't let you override the red hang-up button and if you're looking to press the green call button from within your app, you should also supplement this with an options menu item.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

There is no call to get that kind of info.
You can try having a dictionary with `Build.MODEL` as key.
Something like:

```
/* Create the dictionary */
private HashMap<String, Boolean> redGreenKeys = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
redGreenKeys.put("Milestone", false);


public Boolean hasRedGreenButtons() {
    Boolean ret = redGreenKeys.get(Build.MODEL);
    if ( ret == null )
        return false;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know that.
I think he means the green and red keys with a phone for making a call or hanging up.

Comment: Yes Sephy, Red and green keys means the keys for making a call or hanging up

Comment: oh, then my solution will not work. I Just updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Macarse, But the client actually needs to check this at phone startup. A manual table would require testing and updating his application every time a new phone model was sold anywhere in the world.