# Dealing with Android devices without MENU key

Tags: android, menu

I'm told by some users that my Android app is not usable because their device does not have a MENU key.

What's the best way to deal with these devices? Is it possible to detect if the device lack a MENU key and show a menu button only in this case?

And most importantly, how do you test this in the simulator?

Thanks.

**Edit**: Apparently the problem was that the users didn't know that the Menu key was called the Menu key.

**Edit**: Also, some unofficial Android devices like the Eken and aPad don't have a physical menu key.

Comment: Out of interest, what is this device? Every device I've seen so far, whether or not it has a trackball, direction keys, hard call buttons, or is a tablet device, have had a menu button.

Comment: Asked both of them. One said it's the Motorola Droid, which I'm pretty sure does have a menu button. Sorry, most likely I asked the question too soon.

Comment: Galaxy Nexus doesn't have one either.

Comment: HTC desire C doesnt have menu button as well, it only has `back`, `home`, `app switch` buttons. http://forum.xda-developers.com/deviceForum/screenshots/1985/20121121T062736.jpg

Comment: Samsung Tab 2 does not have menu key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite surprised that there are devices without a <kbd>Menu</kbd> key out there, as stated in my comment.

As this recent question mentions, there isn't really any API provision for detecting this:
[Programatically detect presence of hardware call/hang up keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957168/programatically-detect-if-an-android-phone-have-hard-keys-or-soft-keys)

It would also seem that there is no "menu key" hardware option that you can emulate using an AVD:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html#hardwareopts

Comment: I think @Christopher is right - I think every Android phone has a Menu button, but it might not say "Menu" on it.

Comment: The Compatibility Definition Document (CDD) states that all Android devices must have a MENU key or an equialent gesture, touch panel, etc. http://source.android.com/compatibility/index.html

Comment: Same goes for Home and Back. Hence devices like the X10 which have those buttons and only those buttons below the screen :)

Comment: Actually , there is a way to detect if there is a menu key : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#hasPermanentMenuKey() . However , as you can see , it needs API14 and above in order to work . For API 11-13, you will need to provide an alternative

Answer (score 7):

Starting with Android 3.0 (API level 11), devices are not required to have a dedicated Menu button. (Read more about this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

This means you should provide another way for your users to activate the menu. You can create a button and call [openOptionsMenu();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29) when it is pressed.

Comment: `Device implementation MUST present a Menu key to applications when targetSdkVersion <= 10 and SHOULD
NOT present a Menu key when the targetSdkVersion > 10.`

Comment: which sucks because I liked a clean UI and hide the options

Answer (score 2):

Check if device has menu key:

`ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();`

Comment: Where to enter this text? I am a user.

Comment: Probably in your onCreate() method; this is where you might want to adjust your UI to work around the lack of a menu key.